# Prefix and postfix operators inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

Consider the following code:

```
// Only prefix operators
struct prefix
{
    prefix& operator--() { return *this; }
    prefix& operator++() { return *this; }
};

// Try to represent prefix & postfix operators via inheritance
struct any : prefix
{
    any operator--(int) { return any(); }
    any operator++(int) { return any(); }
};

int main() {

    any a;

    a--;
    a++;
    --a; // no match for ‘operator--’ (operand type is ‘any’)
    ++a; // no match for ‘operator++’ (operand type is ‘any’)

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to create a hierarchy of classes. The base class, only to realize the prefix increment/decrement operators. And to add a postfix versions in derived class.

However, compiler can not find the prefix operation for the derived class object.

Why is this happening, why prefix operators are not inherited?

Comment: They're hidden by the ones in your derived class.

Comment: Just put all your operators in the same class, why make it more complicated?

Comment: @NeilKirk Just for study purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to import the hidden `operator--` and `operator++` of the `prefix` class:

```
struct any : prefix
{
    using prefix::operator--;
    using prefix::operator++;
    any operator--(int) { return any(); }
    any operator++(int) { return any(); }
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0331ae7765851766)

This is probably a terrible idea, but at least it will compile.

Comment: Somehow, I perceived the prefix and postfix forms as different operators. But it's the same thing turns out that the function `f(int)` in the base class and `f(double)` in a derived. Thanks a lot.